# protractor: set timeout for all browser.wait calls

Tags: angular, protractor, webdriver, timeout

browser.wait(..) seems to wait indefinitely, if the optional timeout parameter is not specified. I wanted to specify a default value for all such calls. is there a way to do that?

Comment: you can see all available parameters for config here https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/lib/config.ts I think what you need is something like `allScriptsTimeout` but there are many different timeouts

Answer (score 0):

Sound like you may need to use `browser.sleep()` instead of `browser.wait()` since

> `browser.wait()` Schedules a command to wait for a condition to hold or promise to be resolved.

But anyway you can store the default timeout let's say in your protractor.conf file

`params: {
        defTiemout: 12000,
} // you can put it anywhere and call it whatever`

and than use it

```
browser.sleep(browser.params.defTiemout)
```

Answer (score 0):

Correction: implicit waits are set to `0` by default, but they do not set the timeout for `browser.wait` functions. For those, try my suggestion below:

I just simply made a helper file for my suite:

```
const EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;
const timeOut = 5000;

const helpers = {
    waitForClickable: (element) => browser.wait(EC.elementToBeClickable(element), timeOut),
    waitForPresence: (element) => browser.wait(EC.presenceOf(element), timeOut),
    waitForVisible: (element) => browser.wait(EC.visibilityOf(element), timeOut),
    waitForInvisible: (element) => browser.wait(EC.invisibilityOf(element), timeOut),
    waitForUrl: (text) => browser.wait(EC.urlIs(text), timeOut)
};
module.exports = helpers;
```

Use them like this:

```
it('should wait for element', async () => {
    await helpers.waitForClickable(youElement);
});
```